# Expressions to define repeatable time intervals

Tags: java, time, intervals, cronexpression

I would like to know how to define expressions for repeatable time intervals. There must be general start and end date/time (the end could be empty though). And it must have kind of repeat pattern definition.

There are plenty of use cases e.g.:

- A restaurant offers discount durinng some time (Monday - Friday,
  12:15-14:45)
- A club requires additional fee each Friday 21.00 - Saturday 23:59.
- A monthly payment must be done during 5 days (1st - 5th)

etc.

In general user should be able to define such time interval and passing some date should return a `boolean` result whether the date belongs to the defined interval. I have some experience with `CronExpression` but it can't describe such things.

Is there any alternative or CronExpression extension to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at Quartz: http://quartz-scheduler.org/

It might be what you'll need.

Comment: Thank you but it's based on CronTrigger as described in the tutorial-lesson-06 or you should write yourself pattern how to find next date. In fact it defines repeatable patterns for single date (not intervals).

Comment: http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-06

Comment: Well, then you are indeed using Quartz already ;-)

The reference you gave us provides you with examples.

Check this out as well: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12058_01/doc/doc.1014/e12030/cron_expressions.htm

Comment: I've already tried this. It's not possible e.g. define interval {every day 10:15 - 12:45}. So I should pass 3 dates 10:30, 11:30, 12:30 and get "true"

Comment: You want to schedule: "Monday - Friday, 12:15-14:45" ?

How many times do you like the trigger to fire between this time?

If you wanna know if a current date qualifies between two other dates/times then maybe you should use Joda Time: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I don't want any schedules. What I need is to check whether some service is valid. It's valid during some repeatable time intervals.

Comment: I guess this isn't part of the Quartz framework. Keep the time interval outside of quarts as settings and use Joda Time to check if a given date/time qualifies your condition.